# Ambiguity in Relative Clause

Tags: relative-clauses

Something confused me a lot about relative clause. For example, If I say

> The book of the writer that I like is one of the bestsellers.

What I want to emphasize here that the book of the writer is what I like not writer so is this usage ok ? I mean it sounds to me as if the liked thing is writer here not book.

I just made the sentence up to explain what confuses me.I hope I could explain what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

It is ambiguous. You can resolve this by moving things around:

> The book I like best by this writer is . . . *or*
>   This writer's book I like best is . . .

or by using different words:

> My favorite book by this writer is . . .